# VLookup in Excel gives strange results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I know this should be very simple, but something odd is going on with VLookup in Excel.  I'm using Excel 2003. I know its ancient.  But its what I have.

Heres the scenario

```
Col A           ColumnB     ColumnC
green            asdf       =VLOOKUP($A1,B1:B4,B:B,TRUE)
blue             ggss       =VLOOKUP($A2,B1:B4,B:B,TRUE) 
orange           green      =VLOOKUP($A3,B1:B4,B:B,TRUE)
red              blue       =VLOOKUP($A4,B1:B4,B:B,TRUE)
```

I'd expect this to return:

```
green
blue
#n/a
#n/a
```

but I get

```
#REF! on all lines.
```

I've tried it with TRUE instead of FALSE.  Also, with a range name instead of the B1:B4, with the same results.

I must be missing something here.  I've tried this in Google Apps and in OpenOffice Calc with similar results.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try changing the `B:B` to `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the column range "B:B" for the third argument.

It's looking for a number (numeric column number) `=VLOOKUP($A1, B1:B4, 1, TRUE)`

EDIT: When I replicate your column data as described, I get:

```
   A    |   B   |    C
green   | asdf  | green
blue    | ggss  | asdf
orange  | green | blue
red     | blue  | blue
```

You won't achieve your desired results with `TRUE` as your last argument

Comment: I tried that too.  Doesn't work.  Still gives an error.

Comment: Can you verify that the VLOOKUP formulas are exactly as you've written them, and not copied? Typically, you would use the more static range and you would use `FALSE` to identify it as looking for an exact match: `=VLOOKUP(A1, $B$1:$B$4, 1, FALSE)`

Comment: I'm actually using a named range for the B1:B4 range

Comment: When I use the formula =VLOOKUP($A1,mylist,2,FALSE) in the 3rd column, where mylist is the range B1:B4, I get the following results
#REF!
#REF!
#N/A
#N/A

Comment: Can you verify the integrity of the named range?

Comment: Yes.  Its just 4 fields, B1:B4

Comment: Why are you using `2, FALSE` instead of `1, FALSE`? If you only have 1 column, you need to look for column 1. That's the #REF! error. The other 2 are giving #N/A because they aren't found (when FALSE is in place)

Comment: OK, that's it!  I misunderstood what that parameter was.  Thanks for your help!